# Error en SQL null

Tags: php, sql

tengo un error en SQL + PHP, estoy trayendo una fila con su Determinado ID en mi tabla generos y me aparece el siguiente error cuando tiro un var_dump con el error de la información: **array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }**

Claramente es que no me llegan los datos pero no me doy cuenta como solucionarlo les dejo mi función entera de consulta:

```
function getGEN($Genero_ID){
$query=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM generos WHERE Genero_ID= ?" );
$query->execute(array($Genero_ID));
$genero = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
var_dump($query->errorInfo());
return $genero;


}


Y dejo mi formulario donde voy a mostrar los datos para luego editarlos.

<form class="form-alta" action="editadogen" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Genero_ID" value="{$genero->Genero_ID}">

<div class="form-group row margin-15px">
  <label for="autor" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Genero:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Genero" value="{$genero->Genero}">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row margin-15px">
  <label for="autor" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Edad:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Edad" value="{$genero->Edad}" >
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row margin-15px">
  <div class="col-sm-10  btn-sub-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="submit-create-libro">Editar Genero</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si observas, tienes esto en tu función:

```
var_dump($query->errorInfo());
```

En realidad, con el `var_dump` anterior estarías revisando si hay errores y la salida:

```
array(3) 
{ 
  [0]=> string(5) "00000" 
  [1]=> NULL 
  [2]=> NULL 
}
```

indica que **no ha habido error en la consulta** ([ver Nota de contribución en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php#67194)).

Está bien en fase de desarrollo usar `var_dump` para ver posibles errores, pero aquí ya no hace falta. Al parecer la consulta funciona bien, otra cosa es que traiga datos o no (puede haber `0` filas que cumplan el criterio por ejemplo) si quieres depurar los resultados puedes poner esto: `var_dump($genero);` Así verás lo que hay en los resultados de la consulta en sí misma.

Si tienes todo bien ensamblado en tu código, y si hay filas, deberías estar viendo los datos en tu formulario (no sé si cuando dices que *no me llegan los datos* te refieres a que no ves nada en el formulatio). ¿Se ven los datos en el formulario? Pues listo, quita el `var_dump($query->errorInfo());` y ya está. ¿No se ven los datos en el formulario? Pues pon un `var_dump($genero);` y revisa lo que muestra. Si muestra algo y sigues sin ver nada en el formulario, dinos cómo tienes ensamblado el código. Si no se ve nada, es que el criterio de tu consulta no se cumple. Siempre conviene, antes de pasar a usar datos, verificar que no están vacíos.